# How to return same data in different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have few columns as below:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4
  ID123   Apple   Red     Apple
  ID456   Apple   Blue    Apple
  ID987   Pear    Blue    Apple
  ID899   Pear    Blue    Apple
```

I wanted to pull rows where `column2 = column4` as below:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4
  ID123   Apple   Red     Apple
  ID456   Apple   Blue    Apple
```

I tried:

```
  select column1,column2,column3,column4
  where column2=column4
```

But no result are returned.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your query is fine, are you sure there are data in column2 and column4 that matches equality?

Comment: Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20ff3/2

Comment: Are you getting an error? Because you omitted the 'from table' bit

Comment: You might want to try `WHERE UPPER(column2)=UPPER(column4)` if the collation is Case Sensitive and your data is `apple` in column2 and `Apple` in column4

Comment: Do you have Apple with spaces at the end ?

Comment: I tried this but not working..

Comment: Some of the data like this 'Apple Two' 'Apple One'
is it cause by the space?

Answer (score 1):

As Recommend to you if the collation is Case Sensitive then you should make the columns all the same by using either UPPER or LOWER i would also do a replace for any spaces.

### Example

```
 CREATE TABLE #temp1
(
    column1 NVARCHAR(255),
    column2 NVARCHAR(255),
    column3  NVARCHAR(255),
    column4 NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES('ID123','Apple','Red',' Apple')
INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES('ID456','Apple','Blue','Apple')
INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES('ID987','Pear','Blue','Apple')
INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES('ID899','Pear','Blue','Apple')

SELECT * FROM #temp1
WHERE REPLACE(UPPER(column2), ' ', '' ) = REPLACE(UPPER(column4), ' ', '' )

drop table #temp1
```